# argdef-error with A&A template (renewcommand)

Tags: errors, document-classes, journal

I have two issues with the aa.cls, which can be downloaded from [this](http://ftp.edpsciences.org/pub/aa/readme.html) site. It produces the error

```
! File ended while scanning use of \@argdef.
<insert text>
              \par
1.267 \renewcommand
                   {\Newassociation}[3]{%
```

and the same error like in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274821/aa-latex-template-returns-error-renewcommand) (the temporary fixes suggested in the comments don´t work for me). Both direct me to line 267 of the mentioned aa.cls with

```
\RequirePackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\RequirePackage{answers}
-->    \renewcommand{\Newassociation}[3]{%
    ...
}
```

(the arrow indicates the line, where it directs me).

Like touhami suggests in the comments,  `\Newassociation` is from the `answers`-package. But his solutions don´t work. As it directs me to aa.cls, it recognizes the file. An additional `\usepackage{answers}` in my paper-script didn´t help. What may go wrong?

Additionally - as the problem may be connected, I won´t open another question - it also doesn´t know `\newsolution` in line 303 of the same file and gives

```
! Latex Error: \newsolution undefined.
...
1.303 \renewcommand{\newsolution}
                                 [1]{%
```

I look forward to your answers. Thank you.

Edit:
As it is desired, here my paper-script with the usepackages:

```
\documentclass{aa}

\usepackage{answers}    %included for possible solution, didn´t work
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,}

\definecolor{grau}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\definecolor{hellgrau}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\begin{document}
    ....
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of code starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Also, the link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @egreg I edited my question and included my paper-script. I tested the links. Both should work. The linked question (the second link) directs to the same website with the A&A-template (first link).

Comment: Downloaded class, saved example, runs smoothly, no error.

Comment: My bet is on you having an outdated version of `answers.sty`

Comment: @egreg That actually solved all errors. I uninstalled and re-installed the package. It works like a charme. Thank you. Hopefully I can at least upvote your comment someday.

Comment: @Renatius I'm not adding an answer, because I don't think the question will be useful to other readers, being about a very localized problem, so I'll vote for closing as off-topic. This doesn't mean your question was bad: after the edit it became easy to make a conjecture that eventually solved the issue. We'll wait for other contributions from you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an outdated version of a package, solved with an update.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I also can delete the question, if demanded.